# Why was this identify-this-actor question closed as not constructive?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

Here's [the question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11354/who-is-this-actor-and-from-what-movie-is-he).

I could understand this being closed as off-topic, since it is trivia, or as too localized, since it is extremely specific.  But the "not constructive" rubric says "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion", which does not seem applicable.  It produced no discussion at all, and any potential discussion could be quickly ended by the answer (which I know) and a reference (which I have).

I'm not suggesting it should be re-opened, but I am genuinely puzzled by the rationale
for this particular disposition.

Comment: [Whether identification questions are on topic here is currently being debated on meta](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/967/1887) - if you believe ID questions are on topic you should weigh in on this discussion. The community consensus will determine the future validity of these questions.

Answer (score 2):

i'm at a loss as to why this was closed, as we voted that such image questions are on-topic.